# externaldata strips out url query parameters

Tags: azure-data-explorer

I'm trying to follow the documentation here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/query/externaldata-operator to get externaldata from an endpoint.

This works - fetching from a non-storage URL without query parameters.
This doesn't work - fetching from a non-storage URL with query parameters. (ClientRequestId: KE.RunQuery;ad7de8c0-6b8d-4e1e-aa16-c625aa42db5b)

In the example given above using azure storage, the query parameters are passed in a second param to externaldata.
If I try the same with a non storage URL, it fails with 401. (ClientRequestId: KE.RunQuery;ad7de8c0-6b8d-4e1e-aa16-c625aa42db5b).
From our logs we can see that the query parameters are being stripped out.

This also fails if the entire URL is passed in the first parameter. (ClientRequestId: KE.RunQuery;4bf02402-a158-4d7a-82f9-16769b10a59b)

This isn't an issue with ACL on our side, because this URL with the query params loads successfully outside of Kusto without AAD.